# How to add hyperlink to Excel's cells with C#

Tags: c#, excel, hyperlink

As you see, sometime we need to add a lot of hyperlinks into the Excel file, and as a programmer, you don't want to do it manually but you want to do it programmatically.
I have searched through the Internet but I only find out how to programmatically add Web's hyperlink, not current excel file hyperlink.
So I think it would be a good ideal to find out how to programmatically add current excel file's hyperlink (or local hyperlink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a way to add the hyperlink to the Excel 's cells with the lib Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, but I come up with an ideal that I can add hyperlink through clipboard data.

I have researched the Excel clipboard data and found out that Excel data can be HTML data. So I handle the data as HTML and paste it into Excel - and BAM - we got the hyperlink for Excel 's cells

We got classes like this

```
    class HDNData
    {
        StringBuilder builder;

        public void SetBuilder(StringBuilder dataBuilder)
        {
            this.builder = dataBuilder;
        }

        public string Data { get; set; }
        public string Hyperlink { get; set; }
        public string HexColor { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            builder.Clear();
            bool hasHyperlink = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Hyperlink);
            bool hasColor = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(HexColor);
            if (hasHyperlink)
            {
                builder.Append("<a href=\"");
                builder.Append(Hyperlink);
                builder.Append("\">");
            }
            if(hasColor)
            {
                builder.Append("<span style='color:");
                builder.Append(HexColor);
                builder.Append("'>");
            }

            builder.AppendLine(Data);
            if (hasHyperlink)
                builder.Append("</a>");
            return builder.ToString();
        }
    }
    class HDNHtml
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder cellBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        private List<List<HDNData>> data = new List<List<HDNData>>();

        public void Add(int i, HDNData hdnData)
        {
            if(i < data.Count)
            {
                hdnData.SetBuilder(cellBuilder);
                data[i].Add(hdnData);
            }
            else
            {
                if (i == data.Count)
                {
                    data.Add(new List<HDNData>());
                    hdnData.SetBuilder(cellBuilder);
                    data[i].Add(hdnData);
                }
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            builder.Clear();
            builder.AppendLine("<html>");
            builder.AppendLine("<head></head>");
            builder.AppendLine("<body>");
            builder.AppendLine("<table>");
            builder.AppendLine("<col>");
            foreach (List<HDNData> row in data)
            {
                builder.AppendLine("<tr>");
                foreach (HDNData col in row)
                {
                    builder.AppendLine("<td>");
                    builder.Append(col.ToString());
                    builder.AppendLine("</td>");
                }
                builder.AppendLine("</tr>");
            }
            builder.AppendLine("</table>");
            builder.AppendLine("</body>");
            builder.AppendLine("</html>");
            return builder.ToString();
        }
    }
```

And use the class like this

```
    HDNHtml hdn = new HDNHtml();
    Random r = new Random();
    HDNData hdnData = new HDNData();
    hdnData.Data = r.Next().ToString();
    hdnData.HexColor = "#FFCCFF";
    hdn.Add(0,hdnData);
    hdnData = new HDNData();
    hdnData.Data = r.Next().ToString();
    hdnData.Hyperlink = "#GTA";
    hdn.Add(0, hdnData);
    hdnData = new HDNData();
    hdnData.Data = r.Next().ToString();
    hdnData.Hyperlink = "#GTA";
    hdn.Add(0, hdnData);
    hdnData = new HDNData();
    hdnData.Data = r.Next().ToString();
    hdnData.Hyperlink = "#GTA";
    hdn.Add(1, hdnData);
    hdnData = new HDNData();
    hdnData.Data = r.Next().ToString();
    hdnData.Hyperlink = "#GTA";
    hdn.Add(1, hdnData);
    string data = hdn.ToString();
    txtWarnings.Text = data;
    Clipboard.SetText(data);
```

Now run the code and paste the clipboard data into a Excel 's sheet. Note that in that Excel workbook have to defile a cell name: GTA , thus the excel 's cells' hyperlinks will link to that GTA cell.

Answer (score 5):

Excel supports a [`HYPERLINK()` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HYPERLINK-function-333C7CE6-C5AE-4164-9C47-7DE9B76F577F?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1%20%22Excel%20HYPERLINK%20function):

```
HYPERLINK(link_location, [friendly_name])
```

Take a look at the page I've linked to above for common examples of the `HYPERLINK()` function, such as what you're looking for.

For example, the following formula opens a file, navigates to the *Annual* worksheet and selects F10. The hyperlink text is the contents of cell D1.

```
=HYPERLINK("[http://example.microsoft.com/report/budget report.xlsx]Annual!F10", D1)
```

In the above example, the Excel file is at a HTTP location, but it could equally well be a local path, as shown below:

```
=HYPERLINK("[D:\Documents\budget report.xlsx]Annual!F10", D1)
```